# How to select multiple elements in Android automation

Tags: android, mobile, automation, appium-android

I'm very new to Android Automation. Please help to locate the FOLLOW buttons in the below image. I want to select any 2 FOLLOW buttons. I even tried with List WebElements. But still couldn't crack this.[image]

I've tried the below xpath. But I'm getting NosuchElementException message.

driver.findElementByXPath("//com.onefc.android.app:id/athlete_name_text[@text='Aung La N Sang']/following-sibling::android.widget.RelativeLayout/android.widget.Button").click();

Answer (score 0):

If you want to locate all the "FOLLOW" buttons, you can use this XPath: `//android.widget.Button[@text = 'FOLLOW']`

Comment: I want to follow any 2

Comment: You can use this XPath to get a list of all these buttons (because they all have the same text value) and then, choose any 2 that you like. It will be something like:`List<MobileElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@text = 'FOLLOW']"));`